# Gradient Of Complex Least Squares

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, several-complex-variables

I want to find the gradient of $f : \mathbb{C}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where

$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac 1 2 \Vert \mathbf{Ax} - \mathbf{b} \Vert_2^2,
$$

and $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$, $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^{N}$, $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{C}^{M}$.

For real matrices, it's straightforward, but I am getting stuck with the complex case:

$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac 1 2 ( \mathbf{Ax} - \mathbf{b} )^\mathrm{H} ( \mathbf{Ax} - \mathbf{b} ) = \frac 1 2 ( \mathbf{x}^\mathrm{H} \mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H} \mathbf{Ax} - \mathbf{x}^\mathrm{H} \mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H} \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{b}^\mathrm{H} \mathbf{Ax} + \mathbf{b}^\mathrm{H} \mathbf{b} ).
$$

For the first and thirds terms, the gradient is $2 \mathbf{A}^\mathrm{H} \mathbf{Ax}$ and $\mathbf{b}^\mathrm{H} \mathbf{A}$, respectively. For the fourth term it is $\mathbf{0}$. However, it's the gradient of the second term that has me puzzled and I am wondering if there is something fundamental that I have forgotten. How do I account for the conjugation of $\mathbf{x}$ in the gradient? Is that even possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: But $\mathbf x^H \mathbf A^H\mathbf b = \mathbf b^H\mathbf A \mathbf x$, does it not?

Comment: @TedShifrin They are conjugates of one another, no?

Comment: Oh, sure. Serves me right for not using paper. So what do you mean by gradient?

Comment: You either need to write $z_j = x_j+iy_j$ and compute the $(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)$ gradient, or you need to compute $\partial/\partial z_j$ and $\partial/\partial\bar z_j$. (I'm switching letters here to write complex in terms of two reals, of course.)

Comment: By gradient I mean the $N\times 1$ vector whose $i^\mathrm{th}$ element is $\partial f / \partial x_i$, where $x_i$ is the $i^\mathrm{th}$ element of $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: So you're computing only the "holomorphic part" of the gradient, in which case you lose the $\bar{\mathbf x}$ stuff. But I doubt that is what you really need/want. Since you're considering a real-valued function, you need both the "complex" and "conjugate complex" derivatives to get full information.

Comment: I've been out of school too long to remember what holomorphic means. I'm trying to do some gradient descent type stuff.

Comment: My advice is: Just work in real coordinates. Change your $\mathbf x$ to $\mathbf z$ and write $\mathbf z=\mathbf x+i\mathbf y$ and write it out.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. I suspect that is what I will have to do. I'm pretty sure that it's possible to hack up a linear system in $\mathbb{R}^{2M \times N}$ that is equivalent to this.

Comment: (It's more natural to use $\mathbf z, \bar{\mathbf z}$ as coordinates, but I will let you proceed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a matrix $M$, let me denote its complex conjugate by $M^*$, its transpose by $M^T$ and its hermitian conjugate by $M^H=M^{*T}$.

Write the function in terms of the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and take its differential
$$\eqalign{
  f &= \frac{1}{2}(Ax-b)^*:(Ax-b) \cr\cr
 df &= \frac{1}{2}\Big(A^*\,dx^*:(Ax-b) + (Ax-b)^*:A\,dx\Big) \cr
    &= \frac{1}{2}\Big(dx^*:A^H(Ax-b) + A^T(Ax-b)^*:dx\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
Now the tricky part is to treat $dx^*$ and $dx$ as independent variables.

To find the gradient wrt $x$ you hold $x^*$ constant, i.e. set $\,dx^*=0$, to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \frac{1}{2}A^T(Ax-b)^* \cr\cr
}$$
While holding $x$ constant yields 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^*} &= \frac{1}{2}A^H(Ax-b) \cr\cr
}$$
Notice that the two expressions are complex conjugates of one another, so you only need calculate one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x,\bar{x})=(Ax-b)^*(Ax-b)=(\bar{x}^TA^*-b^*)(Ax-b)$.

$\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial \bar{x}}:k\rightarrow k^TA^*(Ax-b)$; then, for the symmetric bilinear form  $<X,Y>=X^TY$, $\nabla_{\bar{x}}g=A^*(Ax-b)$.

Since $g$ is a real function, $\nabla_{x}g=\overline{\nabla_{\bar{x}}g}=A^T\overline{(Ax-b)}$.